# How to find past flight routes between 1977/82 Latin America and the former Soviet Union?

Tags: air-travel, routes, history, panama, saint-petersburg

I hope, I am in the correct place to post my question:

Is there a way to find past flight routes between Panama City and St. Petersburg (former Leningrad) in the years 1977 to 1982?

To be precise: over which flight route would someone reach to either from Panama City to St. Petersburg and vice versa in the late 1970s?

I would need this information for an historic background check up in my genealogical (family tree) research.

Bonus point: I have heard that especially in Latin America, flights back then would "collect" passengers (part of student exchange programs between Latin America and the former Soviet Union) from capital to capital before the plane would go into the intercontinental flight, e. g. start in Panama City, going to San José, Costa Rica, to Managua, Nicaragua, to Belize City, Belize to ... to Havanna, Cuba. However, I am not sure about this claim.

Comment: maybe try http://aviation.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about aviation histrory

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Back in the 1970s you had very few long direct flights. It was normal for a flight to stop in multiple cities before it arrived at its final destination, more like how a bus works today.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, @ Max, Calchas, and pnuts. I will check the proposed websites!

Comment: I know there were regularly scheduled flights from Moscow and Berlin to Havana and back that refuelled at YQX during that time, as well as irregular flights between other eastern European cities and Latin America that stopped there for fuel. These were technical stops only, I don't think they (intentionally) took on or left passengers in Gander.